# Tesseract in C# and ASPMaker

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspmaker

I have a scenario.
I wanna use Tesseract when I upload an image. But the image is not saved into the local disk yet, just a preview. How to read the image data and applying the Tesseract?

I expected that you guys can help me with this. Cheers!

Comment: *"I wanna use Tesseract when I upload an image. But the image is not saved into the local disk yet, just a preview"* - as in the resulting OCR, the text? or the image itself? if its the later, you [can use javascript blob object to create preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.